# Android Spinner Array Adapter Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am currently creating spinner with a list of fonts as shown below.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_style_dialog, container, false);

    mSpinnerFont = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            new String[] {"System Font", "Helvetica", "Helvetica-Neue", "Impact"});
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerFont.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

However, it is throwing a null pointer exception on the last line. I don't understand how the array has a null value. Thanks for your responses.

Spinner XML Below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.richluick.blocnotes.CustomStyleDialogFragment">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: maybe mSpinnerFont is null!! check the id "R.id.spinnerFont" is it the same as your xml file?

Comment: I posted the XML above. Looks the same to me

Comment: Check to see if your mSpinnerFont is null by debugging or writing out its value to the console. If it is, you may have an id issue to track down.

Comment: obviously mSpinnerFont  is null indeed. Probably you didn't call setCurrentView, or the current view contains some other XML than you think it has

Comment: @Mixaz I added the full onCreateView method for reference. It is within a fragment. Everything seem okay in there?

Comment: @NSouth mSpinnerFont is indeed null so that appears to be the issue. I'm a little confused about the "id issue" though. The have the same id so I am hoping you may be able to elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the issue is here: getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont); it should be view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont);

Comment: @Mixaz Alright thanks! That certainly did the trick

Comment: Shall I submit it as an answer? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont);
```

looks for a view from root view associated with the activity (set by **Activity.setCurrentView()**), while your spinner is inside the view you have just inflated from file (it is not placed to Activity's view hierarchy yet). Fix your code to:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont);
```

Answer (score -1):

1) i have removed

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and

```
tools:context="com.richluick.blocnotes.CustomStyleDialogFragment"
```

and i tested your code, it works perfectly!  i guess the problem is on

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

try to change it to

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

2) If your problem is not fixed, probably your **FrameLayout** is not included in activity view. So

```
  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinnerFont);
```

will always return **Null**

Comment: #1 still didnt work for me. How can I be sure that FrameLayout is included?

Comment: add an id to your frame (in xml), and call getActivity().findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID) to get the view in code